# Unable to find struct in header file

Tags: c, struct, header

I've been working my way through some programs from Jon Erikson's book and i'm having some problems with structs in my header file. I've declared some structs for packet header storage in "myheader-test" but when I try to implement them into the program gcc tells me the structs are undeclared. 
I know the header file is being read as other functions declared in there work in other programs happily. Also when I tried to define the structs int he main() program it told me they had already been declared in the header.

**from myheader-test.h:**

```
#define ETH_ADDR_LEN 6  
#define ETH_HDR_LEN 14  

struct ether_hdr 
{
  unsigned char ether_dest_addr[ETH_ADDR_LEN];  
  unsigned char ether_source_addr[ETH_ADDR_LEN];
  unsigned short ether_type;
};
```

**in main()**

```
#include "myheader-test.h"
```

**from decode funct()**

```
void decode_ethernet(const unsigned char *header_start)
{

  int i; 
  const struct ether_hdr *ethernet_header;

  ethernet_header = (const struct ether_hdr *)header_start;
  printf("[LAYER 2 : ETHERNET HEADER]\n");
  printf("[Source : %02x]", ether_hdr->ether_src_addr[0]);
```

**and from gcc:**

```
    decode_sniff.c: In function ‘decode_ethernet’:
decode_sniff.c:94:29: error: ‘ether_hdr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   printf("[Source : %02x]", ether_hdr->ether_src_addr[0]);
```

I think the problem is in my declaring of the struct within the program function but i've been over similar examples and can't see a difference. I've also tried moving first reference to the structs into main and had the same problem. Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing

```
ether_hdr->ether_src_addr[0]
```

instead of

```
ethernet_header->ether_source[0] 
// or src_addr? dunno why it was different from the declaration before.
```

Comment: Appologies for the difference between eth_src_addr and eth_source - relic of trying to mess about to find the cause of the problem, and thanks very much for the help - i have no idea why i was calling from the struct name instead of what i'd just declared it as. 
Thanks again.